# Android organisation distribution - multiple oranisations

Tags: android, google-play, distribution

I want to do organisation distribution for my app. So I found a solution [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en).

But I have the same app that should be distributed to 3 different companies (same package name). Is this possible or do I have to change the package name in manifest. In the article above is only a remark saying "same app in public and in private store is not possible", but it doesn't say anything about several private stores.

Answer (score 0):

you can make different package and release .This is the fair way i think